# Node command works only with root permissions (sudo node)

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, apt

When I run node without sudo on Linux terminal, I get a `node command not found error`. Running `sudo node` works perfectly. `npm` command also works fine.

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After the upgrade, I couldn't find node, so I had to reinstall it with snap on Ubuntu.

Here's an image of the problem
[Image illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEWPB.png)

Comment: so what happens when you run `/snap/bin/node` as the normal user? It looks to me like you don't have `snap/bin` in your normal user's path, but it is in root's path.

Comment: Running `snap/bin/node` works

Comment: I just solved it with the command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`. Turns out node command probably calls `/usr/bin/nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`
Turns out node was actually trying to call `/usr/bin/nodejs`. Don't know why though