# cannot access node if I am not root and I cannot use it either

Tags: node.js, laravel-mix

When I run this command as root `node -v`  I get `v18.6.0` 
When I run the same command without root I get `bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory. \ When I run this command` node -v `I get`8.13.2`\ When I run the same command without root privileges I get` /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory 
someone explain to me what is going on because I want to use node in my laravel project,
I can neither use it nor delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo snap alias node nodejs`, then restart any terminal windows you have open (or log out then in if not in a desktop environment).

It appears snap packages are run by a link to the snap executable which runs the appropriate command by the environment telling it what the command that started the program was, then looking through its packages for the right one.

(I figured this out thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68125071 and poking around the file system, then messing with `snap` itself.)